# Haskell - Applicative upon Either's Left

Tags: haskell, applicative, either

I'm trying to understand Applicative and Either's Left. Here is the source:

```hs
instance Applicative (Either e) where
    pure          = Right
    Left  e <*> _ = Left e
    Right f <*> r = fmap f r
```

I'm unable to understand the `Left e <*> _ = Left e` part. It makes no sense because this:

```
Left (+3) <*> Right 5
```

Would return `Left (+3)`, while this:

```
Right (+1) <*> Left 3
```

would return `Left 3`. The problem is inconsistency. Why would the do this? I apologize if my question isn't clean enough. Thanks!

Comment: The second example wouldn't return `Left 4`. It would return `Left 3`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, no, the first example returns `Left (+3)`.

Comment: Essentially, the rule is: if either operand is a `Left`, return that (return the first one if both are `Left`), and if both are `Right`, just extract the function and value from them, apply one to the other, and rewrap the result in a `Right`.

Comment: It's not clear what you see the inconsistency as, but if it's the type mismatch between `Left (+3)` and `Left 3`, that's just because the instance is for `Either e` for some fixed `e`, whereas your examples use different `e`s. There need be no relation between the `a` and `b` in `Either a b`, and a more realistic and consistent example would note that both `Left "foo" <*> Right 3` and `Right (+3) <*> Left "foo"` evaluate to `Left "foo"`. Both those take place in the instance for `Either String`.

Comment: You are being confused since you consider `Right function_taking_Int` and `Left some_Int`. Try instead considering what `Right (+1) <*> Left "hello!"` would do. Yes, that's well typed, and uses the `Either String` applicative.

Comment: Can you say carefully what you find inconsistent about this behavior? (For example, what would the "consistent" behavior be, in your mind?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re wondering how `Right … <*> Left …` can still return a `Left`, it’s because of the `fmap` call in this definition:

```
instance Applicative (Either e) where
    pure          = Right
    Left  e <*> _ = Left e
    Right f <*> r = fmap f r
```

If we expand the definition of `fmap` for `Either`, then the definition of `<*>` looks like this:

```
Left  e <*> _ = Left e
Right f <*> r = case r of
  Left e -> Left e
  Right x -> Right (f x)
```

Or, written more symmetrically with all the cases spelled out explicitly:

```
Left  e1 <*> Left  _e2 = Left e1      -- 1
Left  e  <*> Right _x  = Left e       -- 2
Right _f <*> Left  e   = Left e       -- 3
Right f  <*> Right x   = Right (f x)  -- 4
```

I’ve marked with an underscore `_` the values that are discarded.

Notice that the *only* case that returns `Right` is when both inputs are `Right`. In fact, that’s the only time it’s *possible* to return `Right`.

In case (4) we only have a `Right (f :: a -> b)` and a `Right (x :: a)`; we don’t have an `e`, so we can’t return a `Left`, and the only way we have to obtain a `b` is by applying `f` to `x`.

In cases (1), (2), and (3), we must return a `Left`, because at least one of the inputs is `Left`, so we are missing the `a -> b` or the `a` that we would need to produce a `b`.

When *both* inputs are `Left` in case (1), `Either` is biased toward the first argument.

There is a type similar to `Either` called `Validation` which *combines* its “failure” cases, instead of choosing one or the other, but it’s more constrained: it’s only an `Applicative`, while `Either` is both an `Applicative` and a `Monad`.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR, It's an intentional design decision.

You should think of `Right` as the "default" state, and `Left` as the "fallback" state. I do want to make a small correction to your statements above. `Left (+3) <*> Right 5` does not produce `(+3)` as you say, but rather `Left (+3)`. That's an important distinction. The second correction is that `Right (+1) <*> Left 3` procues not `Left 4`, but `Left 3`. Again, this is important to understand what's going on.

The reason why the `<*>` operator cannot be symmetric over `Either` is because the `Left` and `Right` constructors don't take the same type. Let's look at the type of `<*>` specialized to the `Either` functor:

```
(<*>) :: Either a (b -> c) -> Either a b -> Either a c
```

Notice how only the `Right` side of the first argument is required to be a function. This is so that you can use `(<*>)` to chain together arguments like this:

```
Right (+) <$> Right 3 <*> Right 2
> Right 5
```

But if the first argument were `Left 3`:

```
Right (+) <$> Left 3 <*> Right 2
> (Right (+) <$> Left 3) <*> Right 2
> Left 3 <*> Right 2
> Left 3
```

It also means that you can use `(<*>)` in general when `Left` and `Right` don't have the same type. If `Left (+3) <*> Right 5` should produce `Left 8`, then what should `Left (++ "world") <*> Right 5` produce, given that they can both be coerced to the same type, namely `Num a => Either (String -> String) a`? It's impossible to come up with a satisfactory answer that treats `Left` and `Right` equally when they aren't the same type, and a version of `Either` that was restricted to carrying one type would have severely hampered utility.

This also allows you to treat `Left` values as exceptional in some way. If at any stage, you end up with a `Left` value, Haskell will stop performing calculations and just cascade the `Left` value all the way up. This also happens to match up well with the way a lot of people think about programming. You could imagine creating alternate sets of computations for `Left` and `Right` values, but in many cases, you'd just end up filling the `Left` computations with `id` anyways, so this isn't too big a limitation in practice. If you want to execute one of a pair of branching computations, you should use regular branching syntax, such as guards, patterns, or `case` and `if` statements and then wrap the values up in `Either` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this equivalent definition of the instance:

```
instance Applicative (Either e) where
    pure = Right
    lhs <*> rhs = case lhs of
                      Right f -> fmap f rhs
                      otherwise -> lhs
```

If `lhs` isn't a `Right`, it must be a `Left`, and so we return it as-is. We don't actually have to match against the wrapped value at all. If it *is* a `Right`, we defer to the `Functor` instance to find out what gets returned.

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
    fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
    fmap _ l = l
```

Again, I've given a definition that emphasizes that the *content* of the `Left` value doesn't matter. If the second argument isn't a `Right`, we don't have to explicitly match on it; it must be a `Left`, and we can just return it as-is.